# Swagger - Get Generated JSON

Tags: .net, servicestack, swagger

I have a .NET application that uses `Servicestack` for writing services and `Swagger` for documenting the APIs. Everything works fine and i can see in Swagger-UI the generated - *from attributes* - documentation. Is there a way that I can get the generated raw Json (or YAML)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% clear on what you're asking, but if you want to access the JSON used by Swagger UI it's at `/resources` which then returns a different url for each Service, e.g:

- http://test.servicestack.net/resources
- http://test.servicestack.net/resource/hello

If you just want a structured JSON metadata for all your Services and you don't care if it's for Swagger or not you can get it from `/types/metadata.json`, e.g:

- http://test.servicestack.net/types/metadata.json

Answer (score -1):

If you open the file with [Swagger Editor](http://editor.swagger.io),

you can simply download raw JSON, YAML

File>Download JSON, Download YAML.